# Problem with CharacterEncoding trying to obtain Twitter data

Tags: character-encoding, social-media

I'm using Mathematica 11 installed in Ubuntu.

I'm trying to retrieve Twitter data these days. So, I'm using:

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter"]
```

Everything is connecting well and when I use

```
twitter["UserData", "Username" -> "##TWITTERUSERNAME##"]
```

I can read the data.
However, I'm trying to retrieve data with:

```
twitter["UserReplies", "Username" -> "##TWITTERUSERNAME##",  MaxItems -> 25]
```

And I'm getting this repeated several times:

```
$CharacterEncoding: "The byte sequence {240} could not be interpreted as a character in \
the UTF-8 character encoding."
```

I tried applying the following, because I thought it was just a simple problem with CharacterEncoding:

```
$CharacterEncoding = "ASCII"
```

But nothing's happening and I'm stuck with this. I can't seem to apply any of the commands posted in [these examples](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Twitter.html).

Thank you very much for any answer you could give me.

Comment: Looks like the specific TWITTER USERNAME has content that is not UTF-8. Can you share with me the  TWITTER USERNAME which return such content?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I'm using "elonmusk" as the twitter username.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this.

Comment: Can you please provide a query that produces that error? I'm unable to replicate it. Also the output of SystemInformation["Small"]. Thanks